# ngModelChange not triggering when change in ngModel

Tags: angular, typescript, ngmodel, angular-ngmodelchange

I am trying to fire an event when input value changes. I am using `ngModel` with `ngModelChanges`. But its not working

```
HTML
```

```html
<input type="number"
[(ngModel)]='myModel' (change)="myModelChange()" >

<button (click)='changeModel()'>Change</button>
```

```
Typescipt
```

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  myModel: number;
  ngOnInit(){
    this.myModel =100;
  }
  changeModel() {
    this.myModel = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);  
  }
  myModelChange() {
    console.log('changed');
  }
}
```

Example : [Code here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t5utsb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Is it it possible to do this with `ngModelChanges`. If not then is there any other way?

Comment: This is called two way binding. Why aren't you using it ? `[(ngModel)]='myModel'`

Comment: If you change directly at the input you will see you will get the `console.log`.
But you do not have nothing related with your button and your `ngModelChange` or `ngModel`

Comment: @Spritzig This code is just a demo. I want to achieve this in my project

Comment: @trichetriche [(ngModel)] is used for the two way binding like from and to View and component,To use the ngModuleChange we need to split it [()]

Comment: Do you want only when you click button or at the `ngModelChange` method?

Comment: @NareshShetty I know how ngModel is used, thank you though. What I'm asking is why are you doing that, it's a really bad practice and it's the same principle as two way binding.

Comment: My point being that [you don't ask for help on something you think is the answer, but you rather explain your goal](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: @Spritzig I want when there is change in myModel value change. That button is to just change that model value

Comment: @trichetriche My goal is to fire fire an event when there is a change is ngModel value.  I just wanted to achieve that. I didn't find any solution so tried with ngModelChanges

Comment: And why would you fire an event when your model value changes ?

Comment: @trichetriche I have to update few other values based on this model value.

Comment: There we go. Can't you use a custom component, a `ControlValueAccessor` implementation, or simply a reactive form ?

Comment: You can only use the ngModelChange thats make the thing you want.

Comment: @trichetriche If its possible to fire an event like this then  its straight forward solution for me. With other ways I have too many scenarios to consider so

Comment: Then use `(change)` or `(input)`, and other solutions are the same as this one but sure.

Comment: @trichetriche I tried (change) but no luck. Can you please check. Am I missing anything?  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t5utsb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @NareshShetty is this like selective reading or something ? If you had tried the second one, you would have seen it working.

Comment: @trichetriche I had tried (input) before trying ngModelChanges so I didn't mention about that

Comment: @NareshShetty but it works, so why don't you use it ?

Comment: @trichetriche It wasn't working for me.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t5utsb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @NareshShetty you're giving me a working link ...

Comment: @trichetriche It's not. It should print in console if its working

Comment: It does. Have you looked at the console ?

Comment: @trichetriche I wanted it to print on button click. Not after typing in input. Now I disabled the input. Now you might get clear idea about what I was trying to do https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t5utsb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: I see, then why do you need to listen to value changes when you already have a hook, hxixh is your function ?

Comment: @trichetriche I am new to angular 2+. I have no Idea which hook I can use for listening value changes. & whats hxixh ?

Comment: Which * sorry, I'm on phone un a busy street, I don't double check before posting ! And simply bind your logging function to your button click and you're good to go, why do you need to listen to model changes ?

Comment: @trichetriche Actually that button was just to demonstrate the problem. Whenever there is an update in  this.myData I want to fire an event.